# Hosting a remote subdomain?

Tags: apache-2.2, hosting, subdomain

My client site is: xyz.com.br

I have created a demo.xyz.com.br (DNS Record A) pointing to the ip address of my server.

The request is reaching my server.

The problem:

How do I setup Virtual Host on appache to hit the root directory of the 2nd level domain, if the domain is not hosted on my server?

The target folder:
demo.xyz.com.br ->
Document Root   /home/xyz/public_html/public

Error:

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache doe's not resolve de domain name like a normal domain!!

Answer (score 1):

If you've got the A-record set up and the request is reaching your server, then all you need is to set up Apache. Assuming that:

> Error: You don't have permission to access / on this server

is being returned by *your* server (and it should give you the address in the footer) then you probably just need to add a `Location` clause to your VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName demo.xyz.com.br
    # ... other directives ...

    # Add this bit:
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```